# How to select all faces with the same material?

Tags: modeling, texturing, shortcut, selection-tools

If I have a model with 3 textures (blue, red, yellow), and I want to select all (and only) the blue faces from that model, what's the shorcut to do that?
I remember there was one, but now I don't remember what button combinations were correct.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to *Select Similar Material*, which is also accessbile from the Select Menu in *Edit Mode*.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to *deselect* all faces of a material?

Comment: @ Aaron Franke - yes, using the method below from @maddin45, click the Deselect button.

Comment: The Material option seems to be only available in Object mode in Blender 2.81. Not in Edit mode. The Select option answer below seems to work though.

Answer (score 26):

In edit mode there is a button for that in the materials tab:

[image]

This button will add the faces that have this material to the current selection, so make sure you have unselected everything else before clicking that button.

Comment: I want to select the faces to which a specific materials has been applied to. However, it seems that what you show here does not work for newer versions of Blender.I basically want to go over all materials and select (or get indices of) faces to which that specific material has been applied to.  I haven't been able to find a good solution for doing that as of now. I would appreciate if you can take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103307/how-to-get-indices-of-the-faces-to-which-a-material-has-been-applied-to-using-p) and see if you can offer a solution?

Comment: Where is this button in Blender 2.8? I don't see it.

Comment: @AaronFranke You have to be in edit mode.

Comment: An old post but just solved a problem for me - so I will clarify for anyone that follows: **You need to deselect all before clicking the Select button**. Then the button acts as maddin45 describes - and does exactly what the original poster, @beavoru, requested.