# How to identify faces associated with a material?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I'm just wondering how one would go about viewing faces assigned to a particular material? In 3DS Max you can just, from my experience, do it pretty easily. It'll just highlight the faces associated with that material ID. So is there a way to, in the outliner, select the material and then have those faces highlight in the 3D view? I'm asking because I'm making custom LOD's for modular pieces and, as you can imagine, a lot of faces get deleted in the process and I accidentally delete the only face left using a material that the main model is using.

LOD's need to have the same materials and same number of materials applied to them. So I'm trying to work this out, for future reference, so I can identify which material has no geometry associated to it and then fix that.

Thanks!

Comment: This still applies to 2.8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23232/1245. Not sure it is in Outliner in any way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select all faces with the same material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23231/how-to-select-all-faces-with-the-same-material)  Related re part 2 https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwirsabX4LLvAhUTwTgGHWQLA8sQFjAAegQIARAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblender.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F129082%2Fdelete-all-materials-that-arent-assigned-to-a-face&usg=AOvVaw2bqnfJWkJlupKVFP3Gr5xL

Comment: Thanks, guys! The first answer was best suited for my situation but I highly appreciate both of your answers!